# Help solving a routing error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controllers

I have a controller called `form_questions_answers` with a method in it called `modify_rule` but when I perform a post to `/form_questions_answers/modify_rule/60` Rails tells me:

```
Routing Error
No route matches "/form_questions_answers/modify_rule/60" with {:method=>:post}
```

Why is this happening, I have `map.resources :form_question_answers` in routes.rb, and `map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'` at the bottom of the routes.rb file, so why isn't the `modify_rule` action being triggered?

Comment: nm, It turns out I had a spelling error in the action URL - instead of  'form_questions_answers' it should have been - 'form_question_answers' - Once I fixed that error it worked like magic.  Sorry about this, please close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/form_questions_answers/modify_rule/60` would not accept POST on a map.resources basis. It would either be a GET or a PUT in line with REST.

You might want to take a look [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for some info on routes.

Happy turkey day!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using resource based routes you probably want to remove the [default routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#the-default-routes). That said you probably want to add a new member to your `form_question_answers` route like this:

```
map.resources 'form_questions_answers', :member => { :modify_rule => :post }
```

You can read more about adding options to your routes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).